# Yii2, Module error page is not show but it show blank page when error 404

Tags: error-handling, yii2, custom-error-pages

I have tried write my own `actionError` in the module `DefaultController` that just to render error page(HTML only for testing), it also just shows the blank page instead to show the error page.

Am I do the correct way below? It also shows blank page only when i try to access non-exist page within the module path.

In my module class, I have configured the `errorHandler` components within `init()` function as below:

```
public function init()   
{   
    parent::init();   
    // initialize the module with the configuration loaded from config.php   
    \Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config.php'));   

    \Yii::$app->setComponents([
        'errorHandler' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorHandler',
            'errorAction' => 'studconsult/default/error',
        ] // set error action route - this to be error action in DefaultController
    ]);             
}
```

In my `DefaultController` class, I have codes below:

```
public function actions()   
{    
    return [    
        'error' => [    
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',    
        ],    
    ];    
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should simply use this :

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    Yii::$app->errorHandler->errorAction = 'studconsult/default/error';
}
```

Previous answer is not so nice since it will reset the component.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that setComponents replaces only those components that are existing. I guess in your app config there is no such component. The easiest route I have found is create it and register it!

```
public function init()
{

    parent::init();   
    // initialize the module with the configuration loaded from config.php   
    \Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config.php'));  

    //override default error handler
    $handler = new \yii\web\ErrorHandler(['errorAction' => 'studconsult/default/error']);
    Yii::$app->set('errorHandler', $handler);
    $handler->register(); 

}
```

Comment: But in my main config/web.php, actually there is already have this component called '**errorHandler**' which its **errorAction** set to 'site/error' (by default).

Comment: By the way, your answer is works well. :) thanks a lot

Comment: i wanted to upvote, but i unable to.. why ? it said need 15 reputation : (

Comment: Guys, the config @StefanoMtangoo showed is not your main Yii app's config. It is a special config to load specific for your module, where you can define a totally different errorHandler only for that module.